# Crontab seems to execute script, but script doesn't work

Tags: cron, openstack

Running Rhel 7:
I've got a script located at /root/backups/backup.py. It backs up my influxdb shards into swift.

It has a shebang in it. When I execute this command in my shell as root:

```
/root/backups/backup.py
```

it runs and functions correctly.

When I tell my cronjob to run it every 5 minutes, it appears as if it is running in the logs:

```
(root) CMD (/root/backups/backup.py)
```

However, it looks as if it didn't actually work for some reason. When I check, the backup file in swift that this should have created is not there. It is there when I run it from the shell.

I have no idea what the problem is. I've read many things online about the path in the crontab being incorrect. However, I have other cronjobs running that are in the exact same location i.e. /root/backups/
and they are also python scripts. They run once a minute or once every 5 minutes, and they run correctly. What gives?

I don't need any sort of authentication to backup into swift as far as I know. I ssh to the VM, run the command in my console as root without any other authentication, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

It was having some sort of sudo access authentication error:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122616/why-do-i-need-a-tty-to-run-sudo-if-i-can-sudo-without-a-password